# Koma-script not installing in MikTex

Tags: miktex, koma-script

I recently switched over to  LaTeX in VSCode, so I'm kind of a noob at this stuff. I want to use a sty file that uses KOMA commands (if it matters, I'm trying to use evan.sty).

[image: Install]

But instead of installing, VSCode returns "Recipe terminated with error. Retry building the project." This is what appears in `main.log` (Google Doc since Stack Overflow has 30000 character limit): [main.log](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1UwCKR3FSjfXl3ntmVoYgdF7IqAnQGR7a0SVBZmD7iNE/edit?usp=sharing)
Can someone tell me how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: The package `tocstyle` was removed from KOMA-Script proper, see https://ctan.org/ctan-ann/id/mailman.339.1595768614.2548.ctan-ann@ctan.org. It is now only available in https://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script-obsolete, which is not available for easy installation in MikTeX (and neither in TeX live). You can avoid the on-the-fly installation by updating the package database in the MikTeX Console in Admin and User mode. **But** this will *not* solve the underlying problem that your document uses a package that was essentially removed. ...

Comment: ... You should try to get rid of `tocstyle` in your document. If `evan.sty` loads `tocstyle` get in touch with with the author/developer/maintainer of `evan.sty`, tell them about the deprecation and ask them to remove `tocstyle` from the package. As a last resort it would be possible to manually install `tocstyle` from https://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script-obsolete, but this can be a bit tricky, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2063/35864. Since `tocstyle` package is no longer supported, it should probably not be used.